# Can I access context in lazily loaded Svelte component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have this simple Svelte component:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { getContext } from "svelte";
    let value = getContext('test');
</script>

<div>
    <p>{value}</p>
</div>
```

It is lazily loaded inside another component like this (note, this component is compiled completely separately from the lazy component):

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount, setContext } from "svelte";
    let lazyRow = null;
    onMount(async () => {
      try {
        lazyRow = import("http://localhost/wc/row.js");
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
  })
  setContext('test', 'This is my context value');
</script>

{#if lazyRow}
    {#await lazyRow then { default: Row }}
        <Row />
    {/await}
{:else}
<p>Loading</p>
{/if}
```

Unfortunately when the component gets loaded and rendered it bombs out with the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$$')

I would have expected my Row component simply to render the text 'This is my context value', but I get the aforementioned error instead.

I've been googling around for this for a few hours but haven't been able to figure it out. Is it simply not possible to use contexts in lazily loaded components?

**Update**

So I figured out the problem with help from the comments below. The problem is that when the app and components are compiled separately they both include their own version of the svelte internals, so that includes things like `current_component`, etc.
I will have to tweak my build logic in order for the app and components to share the same svelte internals. I'm not sure yet how, but I'll figure it out.

**Update 2**

While it is technically possible to share Svelte internals between an app and an externally loaded lazy component, in the end that isn't going to scale.
So, I have come to the conclusion that this particular route isn't viable for the time being.

Comment: Your example works fine in the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/4d6559ebf71a4c009660b474eb8b289d?version=3.55.0

Comment: If you're getting this error in the browser, I recommend opening the debugger in the developer tools and enabling "Pause on exception" to find out exactly when & where it's happening. It might be worth trying it with both source maps on (examining the .svelte files) and source maps off (examining the compiled code).

Comment: Yea, in the REPL it works fine because it is part of the same build/bundle. What I'm trying to achieve is to compile components completely separately from the main app and lazy loading them afterwards.
So, I guess technically it should be possible, but I'm apparently doing *something* wrong.

Comment: I already checked the source code, the 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$$')' error comes from the fact that the lazy loaded component doesn't have a valid `parent_component` reference. It is unclear though how I can make sure this is assigned properly when lazy loading the component in the way I envision.

Comment: Check whether your row.js is accessing the same svelte module used by the main app, or if it's getting its own copy. If the latter, that will be the cause of your problem, and you'll need to figure out how to reconfigure your build so that there's only one svelte module used by everything (post another question and desribe your tooling/configuration if you need to).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! That sounds plausible since the component is being compiled completely separately from the main app. I'll have a look.

Comment: @PixievoltNo.1 yep, that is exactly the problem. Both my component and app have their own imports of the Svelte internals. I'll need a way to figure out how to share those, but that's a build issue that I'm pretty sure I'll be able to figure out eventually.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The component would just render `undefined` if the context were not to be found.

The problem has to be the import/file itself; it probably does not export a valid/fully compiled component as `default`.

You usually also would not import from localhost via an absolute URL which just breaks when deployed. I would rather expect something like `import('./Row.svelte')` and the build system should take care of the rest (compiling, code splitting, bundling, etc.).

---

While this should work if the component is valid, there is a scenario in which the context would be missing: When the component is constructed via the client-side API.

In this case, the context has to be manually forwarded, e.g. like this:

```js
import { onMount, setContext, getAllContexts } from "svelte";

setContext("test", "This is my context value");
const context = getAllContexts();

onMount(async () => {
    try {
        const Row = await import("./row.svelte").then(m => m.default);
        new Row({ target: document.body, context });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: The component *seems* to be compiled correctly, if I remove the `getContext` call it renders fine. I tried using your example code but that leads to a 'Function called outside component initialization' error.

Comment: The localhost url is there for testing purposes only. Eventually this will be a URL to the same server that the app lives on. Its just that we want to be able to separately compile the components and lazy load them into edge rendered views.

Comment: @RolandZwaga: That seems like bad idea. As Pixievolt No. 1 noted, you can end up with the code using a separate version of the module. As far as I know the recommended way of using components is to import their (pre-processed) `.svelte` code rather than any partially or fully compiled version.

Comment: well, I have now come to the conclusion that it is a bad idea indeed. I can tweak the build to make sure the components will load the same module. But the whole idea behind this is that I want to share components across multiple apps.
If, however, they share svelte internals it would automatically mean that all applications and components are tied to the same svelte version. Which doesn't scale, obviously.

Comment: Ideally I would use web components instead for this purpose, but Svelte's limitation where you can only pass primitive values into a web component is probably going to prove a hurdle. So, I'm going to have to go back to the drawingboard.
Thanks for your input though, I appreciate it.

Comment: I would recommend sharing the components via a (private) NPM package.